# mono iPhoneBackupExtractor.exe

Tags: macos, mono

I'm trying to run the `iphonebackupextracter` software on a MAC OSX 10.8.4. I downloaded the latest version from you web site. and when i run `mono iPhoneBackupExtractor.exe` I get an error. I tried searching for a solution on mono's support site with no luck. Below is the full error message.

Appreciate your help.

```
An unhandled error occurred creating the main form. If running under OS X, this is likely due to a problem with your X11 installation. Please contact support@iphonebackupextractor.com for help.
The error was as follows:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine ---> System.ArgumentException: The requested FontFamily could not be found [GDI+ status: FontFamilyNotFound]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily..ctor (GenericFontFamilies genericFamily) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.FontFamily:.ctor (System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies)
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily.get_GenericSansSerif () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font.CreateFont (System.String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte charSet, Boolean isVertical) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, Single emSize, System.String systemName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Font:.ctor (string,single,string)
  at System.Drawing.SystemFonts.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Theme..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeVisualStyles..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at...ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check).:.ctor ()
  at . (System.String[] ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Stacktrace:

  at.. (bool) <0x00087>
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize () <0x00013>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_virtual_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
```

Native stacktrace:

```
0   mono                                0x000959dc mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   mono                                0x00004a48 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x999758cb _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   ???                                 0x0042c774 0x0 + 4376436
5   ???                                 0x0383b154 0x0 + 58962260
6   ???                                 0x01fe5fa1 0x0 + 33447841
7   mono                                0x00122ee4 mono_gc_run_finalize + 964
8   mono                                0x00264ab3 GC_invoke_finalizers + 179
9   mono                                0x000eaea5 mono_gc_invoke_finalizers + 21
10  mono                                0x00125073 finalizer_thread + 579
11  mono                                0x001eef61 start_wrapper_internal + 641
12  mono                                0x001ef057 start_wrapper + 23
13  mono                                0x0023599e thread_start_routine + 206
14  mono                                0x0026fd68 GC_start_routine + 120
15  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x999895b7 _pthread_start + 344
16  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x99973d4e thread_start + 34
```

Debug info from gdb:

```
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Logs show that there seems to be an issue with creation of UI window panel as the system font the application is trying to look up for could be found on your mac.

There could be 2 main reasons why this could happen:-

1. The latest version of mountain lion (as you point it out to be 10.8.4) does not have that font in their font library
2. The application was created only for windows and developer didn't port it to /tested on mac thoroughly.

if you need to extract your iphone data in urgency then its better to try using a different application which has made for mac and does not require mono

**UPDATE**

Have a look at Total Saver application. It works on mac and windows without the need for you to install any 3rd party frameworks (mono). You'll need JRE (Java Runtime Environment) though.

You can download if for free by simply googling the app name or click on the softpedia link below:-
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Mobile-Phone-Tools/IPhone/Total-Saver.shtml

Link to the product site:- http://www.myphonedata.com/iphone